# Resend activation link for inactive customer with double opt-in

Tags: progressive-web-apps, shopware, shopware6, shopware6-api

When using the [register](https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/store-api/b08a8858e0c5d-register-a-customer) endpoint with enabled double opt-in, the customer gets a registration link. If they do not use the link, the account will be inactive. When the user tries to login later, they will not be able to do so, because the customer is inactive. Is there a way to resend the opt-in link? In the APIs I did not find any information on that topic.